# Colocar más elementos después de un contenedor con position absolute y z-index

Tags: html, css

Como puedo hacer para seguir colocando elementos después de este contenedor que contiene la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito colocar el texto que está de ejemplo y cualquier otro elemento despues de todo ese contenedor, sin usar la propiedad margin-top.
El contenedor, además de tener la imagen, tiene un menú de navegación, el cual está superpuesto con z-index y el fondo tiene un postion:absolute. Cualquier elemento que agrego toma como referencia el elemento del menú.
Adjunto el código html y css.

Contenedor de la imagen html.

```
<div class="home container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 eslogan text-center">
      <!-- <cite>{{cita}}</cite> -->
      <!-- <div class="target rounded-pill"><h1 class="h1">{{titulo}}</h1></div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<app-body></app-body> <!--Este elemento contiene el texto de ejemplo-->
```

Código css del contenedor.

```
.home {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)),
    url("/assets/portada2.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Código del elemento html de texto de ejemplo.

```
<div class="body-container container-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-7 section2">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. EExcepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.xcepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
</div>
```

Código css del elemento anterior

```
.body-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
.section2 {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Aquí no sé que propiedades mas agregar para obtener lo que quiero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que el elemento, `.home` tiene posición absoluta sus elementos hermanos ocuparan su espacio. Deberás establecer un elemento hermano que ocupe la posición que home dejo de ocupar, y de hay en adelante los otros seguirán su posición normal.

Ejem: Si `home` ocupara `2px`, su posición normal si alterar seria la siguiente.

```
?
1 ----- .home (relative)
2 -----
3 ----- .brother(relative)
```

Pero al ser absoluta pasara a un segundo "plano" donde su posición no valdrá en absoluto. así pues `.brother` ocupara automáticamente su espacio.

```
  ----- .home (absolute)
? ----- 
1 ----- .brother(relative)
2
3
```

Lo que deseas es que `.brohter` aparezca en la posición `3px`, para lograrlo debe entonces
crear otro hermano llamado eje: `.home_content` ( que tendrá el mismo tamaño que `.home` pero su posición será relativa así este simulara el contenido ósea los `2px` que dejo de ocupar `home`).

```
  ----- .home (absolute, altura:2px)
? ----- 
1 ----- .home_content(relative, altura:2px)
2 -----
3 ----- .brother (relative)
```

El código html seria algo asi.

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 100;
}

.home {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.home_content {
  height: 70px; /*menu + home*/
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="menu">Menu Menu</div>
<div class="home">
 Soy un home
</div>
<div class="home_content">
 <!-- no me veras pero estoy hay soy home_content -->
</div>
<div class="content_2 content">
contenido 2
</div>
<div class="content_3 content">
contenido 3
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda y por la explicación, me ayudó mucho !